# SQL Query returning null values for Boolean fields from Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, automationstudio

I have 2 Standard Data Extensions and an automation written to get values from one DE to other. The issue I am facing is Boolean values from one DE is not copying exactly in the other DE. False values are being shown as null. I am using * to fetch all fields in the query activity in automation and number of fields in both the DE are same.

This is image of the source DE

[image]

This is image of the target DE
[image]

Comment: Can you please also share the SQL query you used, so that it will be helpful for the community to debug the issue easier.

Comment: @VishalKumarCV I am just using steric to get all feilds from Data Extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and that is to explicitly mention all of the fields in the Data extension. It is working fine for me.